# Warning: session_start() failed: No such file or directory

Tags: php, warnings, session-state

I'm trying to install [berta](http://berta.hungry.lv/) (v 0.6.3b) and I get this error:

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]:
>   open(/var/php_sessions/sess_a0d6b8422181739d10066fb60cebfe5d, O_RDWR)
>   failed: No such file or directory (2) in
>   /hermes/bosweb/web010/b100/ipg.ellieniemeyercom/engine/_classes/class.bertasecurity.php

on line 75 The error seems to happen on line 75 of `class.bertasecurity.php` ([view source code](http://pastebin.com/Ug6Ke2Gx))

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make sure that session directory is writable or you can set a path yourself with:

[`session_save_path`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php)

[This comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php#98106) is also useful if you are using above function.

Comment: thank you, could you provide more detailed code on how that would be set to an example directory?

Comment: @Mohammad: You can visit the link i have provided for comprehensive docs and more useful comments by different people :)

Comment: Bad answer. First of all, on SO you should give answers, not links to answers, because links change. Second of all, the linked instructions produce nothing but errors, `session_save_path(): Session save path cannot be changed when a session is active` and ` PHP Warning:  ini_set(): Session ini settings cannot be changed when a session is active`. Even editing php.ini instead and restarting apache doesn't fix the problem, either.

Answer (score 3):

I think the folder containing the session data cannot be accessed by the PHP process.

If you have not touched your php.ini, the default [`session.save_handler`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler) should be *files* (which means that session data will be stored in a folder on your file system). The value of [`session.save_path`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) contains that folder, you should check that it exists and its permissions for your php process.

Comment: would something like `echo session.save_path;` do it?

Comment: These are ini-values (configuration values for the PHP process) You can modify them using `ini_set()`. Have a look at the official explanation (and the links I provided in the answer): http://de.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php

Comment: i just checked and the value for `session_save_path()` is
`/var/php_sessions/`

Comment: so i suppose i don't have write permissions in that folder.

Answer (score 3):

If you're changing the path that is being used for sessions.

You also might consider, fixing this problem by changing `session.save_path` variable in your `php.ini` file.

Then you'll be fixing in your configuration file and not only in your script.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions are saved on the harddisk of your server. Most likely your session save path does not exist. Try setting it to a directory that does exist or that you have read/write rights to.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this problem when migrating a website from a cPanel server to a different host.

The `session.save_path` was configured in `php.ini` and `.user.ini` inside our `public_html/` folder, and was presumably overwriting a default path the host would have wanted to use.

We decided the files were not needed at all, just a hangover from the old server, and deleted/renamed them out of the way, and this fixed the problem.