# Fail to write session Data and open session file

Tags: php, server

On my server shows suddenly comes error that fail to write session data and fail to open session file i am stuck help me to solve this see image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Reason**

The session file does not exists or the php process cannot access the session file for writing.

**Fix**

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3262756/2534055) answer