# I cannot access my phpMyadmin (MAMP)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mamp

So, I was trying to access my databases through phpMyAdmin yet I was not able to get through because of this error.

```
Warning in ./libraries/session.inc.php#101
 session_start(): open(/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/sess_f985b71806a5f4156e0d6e7b5cf40af535202552, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)

Backtrace

./libraries/session.inc.php#101: session_start()
./libraries/common.inc.php#349: require(./libraries/session.inc.php)
./index.php#12: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)
```

I tried googling it but I cannot find an answer, I really hope someone can help me.

Is it possible I can reset the sessions using terminal?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: session\_start() failed: No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262727/warning-session-start-failed-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Can I reset it using terminal?

Comment: Yes. Just create `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/` and make sure it is writable by the PHP process.

Comment: it returned  `-bash: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/: No such file or directory` @Chris

Comment: Yes, that's the same thing the original PHP error told you. That directory doesn't exist. You need to create it.

Comment: can you give me a guide how to do it? @Chris

Comment: @chris I tried but it doesn't accept the password, I posted the screenshots below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running

```
sudo mkdir -p /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/
sudo chmod -R 0777 /Applications/MAMP/tmp/
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't accept the password, I posted the screenshots below.

Comment: @avlz, did you see my comment on your answer? When it asks for your password, it means the password to the account on your computer, not your MySQL password